# Generating JSDoc from OpenAPI Spec

Tags: node.js, npm, swagger, documentation, openapi

I have an OpenAPI spec from an API service I use (in the form of a `swagger.json` file). I would like to expedite the dev process for generating my endpoints and it would be nice to have them documented with JSDoc to keep things running smoothly in VS Code.

I have found several JSDoc-to-Swagger/OpenAPI parsers and OpenAPI renderers, e.g.:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdoc-to-oas?activeTab=readme
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-comment-parser
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jsdoc-swagger

However, these packages take JSDoc as the input, and render the Swagger / OpenAPI spec as the output. I'm looking to do the reverse. Google has not been helpful and I haven't seen much on StackOverflow either.

Does anyone have any recommendations short of implementing my own package for this?

Comment: Not necessarily an answer to your question - but I have found that if you have a package that gets you most of the way: You can go to the Dependencies tab to find the tools THEY used to make what they do, then go to the ones that depend on that package.  It has saved me lots of time on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-node-codegen) package will generate code for you from your swagger, not exactly what you are after, but might be worth looking into.

Comment: Thank you! That package was a great start. Templating with handlebars.js was ultimately a good solution and the package had some good boilerplate code to reference for my purposes. Thanks again!